# What is the difference between a shallow copy and a deep copy with JavaScript arrays?

Tags: javascript, arrays

According the MDN documentation calling `array.slice()` will create a shallow copy of the array.

See this [MDN link for slice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice).

However, if I run a simple test as such in the console:

```
var test = [[1,2,3],7,8,9];
var shallow_copy = test.slice();
```

and inspect shallow_copy, I can see that the entire 2 dimensional array appears to be copied over.

What is the difference between a shallow copy and a deep copy?  If I were to guess, I would have called this a deep copy.

Comment: It means that `test[0] === shallow_copy[0]`, they refer to the same array object.

Comment: I find the use of the word 'shallow' and 'deep' totally confusing in JavaScript documentation as it is already said that objects are never copied. When it explicitly reads 'shallow' I would expect all elements to be references to the same thing (including non objects such as numbers), but it only applies to objects, which are already stated never to be copied.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

To see the difference, try:

```
shallow_copy[0][2] = 4;
console.dir(test);
```

You'll see that `test` has been modified! This is because while you may have copied the values to the new array, the nested array is still the same one.

A deep copy would recursively perform shallow copies until everything is a new copy of the original.

Comment: thanks for the clear explanation. I was looking for the same from quite a time

Answer (score 2):

Basically you're just getting a reference to the original variable/array. Changing the reference will also change the original array. You need to loop over the values of the original array and form a copy.

Consider this example:

```
var orig = {  a: 'A', b: 'B', c: 'C' };
```

Let's say you want to create a duplicate of this, so that even if you change the original values, you can always return to the original.

I can do this:

```
var dup = orig; //Shallow copy!
```

If we change a value:

```
dup.a = 'Apple';
```

This statement will also change `a` from `orig`, since we have a shallow copy, or a reference to var `orig`. This means, you're losing the original data as well.

But, creating a brand new variable by using the properties from the original `orig` variable, you can create a deep copy.

```
var dup = { a: orig.a, b: orig.b, c: orig.c }; //Deep copy!
```

Now if you change `dup.a`, it will only affect `dup` and not `orig`.

Comment: That's not a shallow copy. That's not a copy at all.

Comment: I may be wrong, please feel free to correct! This is what I learnt from an old experience.

Comment: This is just passing the reference not shallow or deep copy. Look at the best answer at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/184710/what-is-the-difference-between-a-deep-copy-and-a-shallow-copy for the difference between shallow and deep copy. Also what you refer as "deep copy" in your example is actually a shallow one