# How to make push, unshift, pop and shift to work only with local array in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

I have a function to describe my problem:

```js
function testingFunc(value) {
  var temp = value;
  console.log("temp before:    " + JSON.stringify(temp));
  console.log("arrayTest before:    " + JSON.stringify(arrayTest));
  temp.unshift(123);
  console.log("temp after unshift:    " + JSON.stringify(temp));
  console.log("arrayTest after unshift:    " + JSON.stringify(arrayTest));
  temp.push(456);
  console.log("temp after push:    " + JSON.stringify(temp));
  console.log("arrayTest after push:    " + JSON.stringify(arrayTest));
  temp.shift();
  console.log("temp after shift:    " + JSON.stringify(temp));
  console.log("arrayTest after shift:    " + JSON.stringify(arrayTest));
  temp.pop();
  console.log("temp after pop:    " + JSON.stringify(temp));
  console.log("arrayTest after pop:    " + JSON.stringify(arrayTest));
  return temp;
}

var arrayTest = [1,2,3,4,5];
var arrayTestTwo;

arrayTestTwo = testingFunc(arrayTest);
console.log("arrayTest after testingFunc:    " + JSON.stringify(arrayTest));
console.log("arrayTestTwo:    " + JSON.stringify(arrayTestTwo));
```

As you can see, `arrayTest` will change too if `temp` change by using `push`, `unshift`, `pop` and `shift` to edit it's data.

But I want those function to work ONLY with `temp` and ignore `arrayTest`.

Is it possible? Also is it possible to work with object contains functions?

And why is this happen?

Comment: `var temp = value;` - that doesn't actually make a copy of the array. You now have one more variable referring to the same array.

Comment: what you're looking for is a deep copy...

Comment: Doing `arr.slice()` would create a shallow copy

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you assign an array to a variable (or passing it as an argument to a function), you are only storing a *reference* to that array. If two or more variables are referencing the same array, making changes to one will affect all the others as well:

```js
var original = [];
var modified = original;
console.log(original, modified); // [] []

modified.push(1, 2, 3);
console.log(original, modified); // [1,2,3] [1,2,3]
```

The way to solve this is to make a *copy* of the array. To make a copy of an array, you just call [`array.slice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice):

```js
var original = [];
var modified = original.slice();
console.log(original, modified); // [] []

modified.push(1, 2, 3);
console.log(original, modified); // [] [1,2,3]
```

Comment: +1 for the slice() comment. This is a really quick and dirty approach to copying an array that is not talked about nearly enough.

Answer (score 2):

You should have a look at concepts such as:

1. Pure Functions: http://www.nicoespeon.com/en/2015/01/pure-functions-javascript/
2. Immutable Patterns: https://www.sitepoint.com/immutability-javascript/
3. Difference between `value` and `reference`: [Is JavaScript a pass-by-reference or pass-by-value language?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/518000/is-javascript-a-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value-language)
4. How to make a shallow copy or a deep copy: [What is the difference between a shallow copy and a deep copy with JavaScript arrays?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24512712/what-is-the-difference-between-a-shallow-copy-and-a-deep-copy-with-javascript-ar)

---

Basically `primitives` are always `passed by value`, `object` are always `passed by reference`.

```js
// Using Primitives:
var a = "Hello";
var b = a;

b += " World";

console.log('a', a);
console.log('b', b);


//Using References
var a = { hello: "Hello" };
var b = a;

b.hello += ' World';
console.log('a', a);
console.log('b', b);
// As you can see, because b is just a reference to a, editing b you're editing a too.
```

So, following what I said above, you need to make a copy of that objects:

```js
var a = { hello: 'Hello' };
var b = Object.assign(Object.create(null), a);
//Object.assign is es-next, you need for a polyfill
b.hello += ' World';

console.log('a', a);
console.log('b', b);
```

Making `shallow copy of arrays` is a bit more easy because there are many native methods: `Array.prototype.map, Array.prototype.reduce, Array.prototype.filter, Array.prototype.concat, etc...`;

Answer (score 0):

Arrays, just like any object, are passed by reference. That means your temp is an *alias* to *arrayTest*. If you don't want to modify the array outside of the function, create a copy.

A shallow copy is all you need if you stick to .push(), .pop(), .shift() and .unshift(), because these will not change any of the array's elements, even if they are references themselves (non-primitive).

For an array shallow copy, use .slice()

Reading the description will help:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice

Answer (score 0):

There are some popular libraries to circumvent that problem for Arrays, Objects. etc., for example [immutable.js](https://github.com/facebook/immutable-js) from Facebook.