# Am I mutating the redux state in reducer?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, immutability

I am trying to change one item in of an array in my state using a reducer.

State looks like:

```
state: {
  items: [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: 'Superman',
    wearsCape: true
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'Batman',
    wearsCape: true
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: 'Iron Man',
    wearsCape: false
  }
];
}
```

I am trying to filter through all the items in the state to search for first occurance of a superhero that has name equal `sHero.name`. Then I am trying to change a property of found superhero. The reducer code looks like:

```
function findCapedCrusader(state, { sHero }) {
  var result = state.items.filter(s => {
    return s.name === sHero.name;
  });

  result[0].wearsCape = false;

  return { ...state };
```

}

Am I mutating the state by doing the above??

NOTE: apologies for stupid example. I am new to react and redux.

Comment: No because `.filter()`, like `.map()`, returns a completely new array.

Comment: Actually, OP mutates the original state. `.filter` returns the same referenced object and there is a property change.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, `filter` method returns a new array but the returned elements still reference the old ones. So, if someone mutates a property to the newly created array they also mutate the original one.

```js
const state = {
  items: [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: 'Superman',
    wearsCape: true
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'Batman',
    wearsCape: true
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: 'Iron Man',
    wearsCape: false
  }
]
};

const newItem = state.items.filter( s => s.name === "Superman");

newItem[0].wearsCape = false;

console.log( "newitem", newItem, "\noriginal", state.items[0] );
```

If you want to change one object's property in the array and update your state:

```js
const state = {
  items: [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: 'Superman',
    wearsCape: true
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'Batman',
    wearsCape: true
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: 'Iron Man',
    wearsCape: false
  }
]
};

const newItems = state.items.map( s => {
  if( s.name === "Superman") {
    return { ...s, wearsCape: false };
  }
  return s;
});

console.log( "new items", newItems, "original", state.items );
```

As you can see, the original `items` is not mutated. For your situation it will be something like that:

```
function findCapedCrusader(state, { sHero }) {
  var newItems = state.items.map(s => {
    if (s.name === sHero.name ) {
        return { ...s, wearsCape = false }
    }
    return s;
  });
  return { ...state, items: newItems };
}
```

Again, this function will change one object's property and does not change anything else. I'm not quite sure this is what you want since you are trying a `filter` in your question. If you want to update your state with one single object, I can suggest another solution.

Answer (score 0):

The `filter()` method is returning a new array instance, so you are not mutating your state. For more information, see the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

> ### Return value
>
> A new array with each element being the result of the callback function.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you are mutating your state in this example. While `filter` does produce a new array, it is really only a shallow copy of the original. The elements of your `state.items` array are objects, so when you modify one in your new `results` array (which contains pointers to the original contents of `state.items`) you modify the original object. See this answer for a bit more on deep vs shallow copies: [What is the difference between a shallow copy and a deep copy with JavaScript arrays?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24512712/what-is-the-difference-between-a-shallow-copy-and-a-deep-copy-with-javascript-ar?answertab=votes#tab-top)

To fix this you can either:

**1.** Use the spread operator on `result` and then overwrite the value of `wearsCape` like this:

```
result = state.items.filter(s => s.name === sHero.name).map(s => {
    return {...s, wearsCape: false}
});
```

This method works with serializable and non-serializable data and is the recommended way to update nested state values.

Or

**2.** Make a deep copy of `state.items` before filtering:

```
const results = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(state.items)).filter(s => {
    return s.name === sHero.name;
});
```

This method is a bit strange but works well for serializable data in cases where the value you want to modify is deeply nested and using the spread operator (`...`) many times would become cumbersome.

Comment: Or use `newState = Object.assign({}, state)` to make a deep copy of your original state.

Comment: @nbwoodward, actually `Object.assign` also, make shallow copies. [See here.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign#Deep_Clone)

Comment: @devserkan oh wow interesting. Stringify/parse seems like a really hacky solution. I almost always end up using the ImmutableJS library with redux to avoid the potential for this sort of problem.

Comment: @nbwoodward, yes it is really hacky and also not my solution :D In addition to that this way does not work if your object is not serializable. It is better using other methods and somehow update the object without mutating it.

Answer (score 0):

You are. Even though the filter function will produce a new array, the state is in the objects you return in that new array. Based on that, you are changing the state, which does not comply which what a pure function is.

Here I leave you with a good post that will help you to understand better what a deep copy is and how to accomplish it.

https://medium.com/@tkssharma/objects-in-javascript-object-assign-deep-copy-64106c9aefab