# Cloned my array, and yet the original array keeps getting modified. Why?

Tags: javascript

```
const queenThreat = function (board) {
  let collision = false;
  let newBoard = board.slice(0);
  // Horizontal
  let horizontal = newBoard[whiteQueen[0]];
  horizontal.splice(5, 1, 0);
  collision = horizontal.includes(1)
  return board;

// Original array

[ [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0 ],
  [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ],
  [ 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ],
  [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ],
  [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ],
  [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ],
  [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ],
  [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ] ]
// Original array after above code despite cloning the array and only accessing the cloned array

[ [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ],
  [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ],
  [ 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ],
  [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ],
  [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ],
  [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ],
  [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ],
  [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ] ]
```

I've cloned my array using slice(), accessed it instead of the original array under //Horizontal, and yet when I return the original array it's STILL modified. What am I doing wrong? I've tried every way to create a clone of the array and they all somehow modify the original despite never accessing it.

Comment: Search for: ["\[javascript\] array shallow clone"](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavascript%5D+array+shallow+clone). There are _many_ duplicates.

Comment: The first paragraph of https://stackoverflow.com/a/597726/2864740 seems nice an succinct (arrays are objects too).

Comment: In an array of numbers, using `.slice()` will result in a new array that, no matter how its modified, won't affect the original array. But you have an array *of arrays*. Specifically, an array of *references to* arrays. You do copy the array, but the new one has the same references as the old one - to the same data. They both still point to the same data. You'll need new references to new copies of all the inner arrays if you want them to not change.

Answer (score 2):

This is because `.slice()` only performs a shallow copy, therefore some of the values are still referenced from the original array. Please see more detailed explanation in the answers to this question: [What is the difference between a shallow copy and a deep copy with JavaScript arrays?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24512712/what-is-the-difference-between-a-shallow-copy-and-a-deep-copy-with-javascript-ar)

Answer (score 2):

```
let newBoard = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(board));
```

This did the trick. I figured it had something to do with being a shallow copy, but then I'm not sure what the point of creating a copy of the same array is if you can't separately modify it?

Comment: Perhaps an example would help: If you have every student array that contains the same teacher data, you may only want to update the teacher data once. Creating a new student array from another student array, would accomplish that, without breaking the teacher linkage.  Your question uses a multi-dimensional array that is uniform in dimensions, like a matrix; however, that isn't always the case.  An array can have some elements being string, numeric, and other object/arrays that are not uniform in dimension or type.  Had you edited one of those non-object elements, it would have been mutable.

Comment: You *can* separately modify it. You can set `newBoard[0] = someNewData` without it modifying `board`. This is what it means to be a shallow copy. But since both the original and copy contain *references to the same arrays* that haven't been cloned (all the inner arrays), accessing those references and modifying *their* data still modifies it for both.

Comment: Ahh that makes sense. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`Array.prototype.slice()` does a shallow clone. Which means if the array is contains objects, the clone will be referring to the same object.

`board` is a 2-dimensional array. Each element in this array is an array. `board.slice()` provides a shallow copy of the `board`. If you do something like `newBoard[0] = ....`, original `board` doesn't change. But each element within `newBoard`, for example `newBoard[0]` is still referring to the same object as before `board[0]`. Any change in the form of `newBoard[0][0] = ...` will also update `board[0][0]`.

In order to fix this, you'd need to deep clone. There are libraries performing this already. But if your use case is just 2-dimensional array, you could do something like this:

```
newBoard = board.map(row => row.slice());
```